# React not fetching data from Node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am learning Node.JS and using React to fetch the data from the backend of the Node.JS.
 I tested the API of Express in Postman and it was working fine. But when I am using the fetch API, it's not storing the result in the Hooks nor is giving an error. I am trying to display the number of upvotes stored in the Mongodb db using React. I am not getting any error though. React is printing the original data passed in the useState. Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import articles from "./Content";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ArticleList from "../components/ArticleList";

const Articles = ({ match }) => {
  const name = match.params.name;

  const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] = useState({ upvotes: 0, comments: [] });
  //fetching url name/handle from the articles Route path



  useEffect(() => {

fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/articles/${name}`,{ mode: 'no-cors' })
.then(res => res.json())
.then(
  (result) => {
    setArticleInfo(result)
    console.log("result"+result)
  },
  // Note: it's important to handle errors here
  // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
  // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
  (error) => {
   console.log(error);
    });
  }
)

  console.log("after use effect"+articleInfo);
  //Return name if url path matches the name of the article
  const foundArticle = articles.find((article) => article.name === name);
  //display articles except the current one
  const otherArticles = articles.filter((article) => article.name !== name);

  return (
    <div>
      {foundArticle ? (
        <div>
          <p>Total likes: {articleInfo.upvotes}</p>
          <h2>{foundArticle.title}</h2>
          <p>{foundArticle.content}</p>

          <Link className="btn" to="/articles-all">
            All blog
          </Link>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <h4>Not found</h4>
      )}
      <ArticleList articles={otherArticles} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Articles;
```

Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/api/articles/:name", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const articleName = req.params.name;

    // Establishing connection with local MongoDB
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,

    });
    const db = client.db("blogapp");

    //Finding url param in the db
    const articleInfo = await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .findOne({ name: articleName });
    res.status(200).json(articleInfo);

    client.close();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error connecting to db", error });
  }
});
//For likes
app.post("/api/articles/:name/likes", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const articleName = req.params.name;
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    const db = client.db("blogapp");
    const foundArticle = await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .findOne({ name: articleName });
    const addLikes = foundArticle.upvotes + 1;
    const updateLikes = { $set: { upvotes: addLikes } };
    await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .updateOne({ name: articleName }, updateLikes);

    const updated = await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .findOne({ name: articleName });
    res.status(200).json(updated);
    client.close();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("update failed");
  }
});

//For comments
app.post("/api/articles/:name/comment", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { user, text } = req.body;
    const articleName = req.params.name;
    const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    const db = client.db("blogapp");

    const foundName = await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .findOne({ name: articleName });
    const store = foundName.comments.concat(user, text);
    const addComment = { $set: { comments: store } };

    const update = await db
      .collection("articlesdb")
      .updateOne({ name: articleName }, addComment);
    const show = await db.collection("articlesdb").findOne({ name: articleName });

    res.status(200).json(show);
    client.close();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("update failed");
  }

  // res.status(200).send(articlesinfo[articleName].comments);
});
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("listening on port 5000"));
```

Data in Mongodb:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed7295fdba52a9d584c0453"),
        "name" : "learn-react",
        "upvotes" : 3,
        "comments" : [ ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed7295fdba52a9d584c0454"),
        "name" : "learn-node",
        "upvotes" : 10,
        "comments" : [ ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed7295fdba52a9d584c0455"),
        "name" : "learn-cv",
        "upvotes" : 2,
        "comments" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: You are setting an object having 4 properties with a state object that holds just 2 properties that are upvotes, comments. After recving the result try doing something like this : `setArticleInfo({upvote:result.data.upvote, comments:[...result.data.comments]})

Comment: That doesn't solve it either. Looks like the data isn't been read by the Fetch API.

Comment: I guess you are receiving an array of objects from the db, however your initial state is an object, try changing ur initial state to an array to hold array of objects. See if this works. `useState([])`